# Excel - Help adding dynamic header to countifs statement

Tags: excel

Good afternoon, I'm running into some trouble converting the following formula.  My headers are dynamic and i've been struggling trying to figure out how to do that.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
In row 1 I will have the headers I want to dynamically search for.

```
COUNTIFS(Data!AP:AP,"<"&TODAY(),Data!AQ:AQ,"P")
```

Thank you!

Comment: So you want `AP:AP` and `AQ:AQ` to change to the correct column based on where two values can be found in Row 1?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Scott. Yes both of those columns (AP:AP & AQ:AQ) would correspond to a value in row 1 which are the columns I need to dynamically find.  I've done calculations like this before but I can't seem to work this correctly.

Comment: A sample data would be great